# How to iterate over a collection of objects in struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, iterator

I am not able to iterate a collection stored in an user object in struts2.

My struts actions, form and user beans are:

```
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    // getter and setter for name & id
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private List<Project> projects;
    :
    :
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
      // fetch projects from database and add to projects

      return projects;
    }
}

pulbic class login extends ActionSupport {
    private User user;
    public String execute() {
       user = new User();
       return SUCCESS;
    }

    public User getUser () {
      return user;
    }
}
```

Now, on jsp page, I need to display all projects of an user

JSP Code:

```
   <s:iterator value="user.projects" var="proj" status="key">           
        <td> <s:property value="${proj.name}" /> </td>  
        <td> <s:property value="${proj.id}" /> </td>  
    </s:iterator>
```

But this iterator is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: When you say not working, you should explain what exactly is happening - whether an exception is being thrown, whether the page displays nothing, etc.

Comment: Its not displaying anything..... Struts2 is not able to call getUser() and user.getAlbums() methods from <s:iterator>. I don't know the reason for this. Struts 1.3 supported method (getters) call of nested elements; like "user.albums" would actually call getUser().getAlbums(). But it seams strut2 does not support this kind of access.

Comment: @Saumesh Of course it (technically OGNL) allows this type of access. You'll need to provide much more detail in order to get any useful help.

Answer (score 3):

The var attribute is probably unneeded as the iterator pushes that item to the top of the stack...

```
<s:iterator value="user.projects">           
    <td> <s:property value="name" /> </td> 
    <td> <s:property value="id" /> </td>  
</s:iterator>
```

Note if you want to wrap expressions with {} they should be prefixed with %{} to denote OGNL, where ${} denotes EL. You only need to wrap expressions within struts2 tags with %{} if they are not evaluated by default, since it generally makes sense to evaluate in some contexts and not others you won't need to do this often as the tag attributes evaluate/or not as most people would expect.

Comment: Please check the green check box to the left of this question, if this has resolved your issue. Also you might want to consider subscribing to the struts2 tag, it is educational if you are new to struts2 to read the questions and answers.